# 64bit compiler for wxDev-C++

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ide

I am using "wxDev-C++" for creating a DLL on my Windows 7, 64bit machine.
However it seems the DLLs created are in 32 bit platform format.

I think it is because the included compiler is a MingW 32 bit compiler.

Question:

1. How can I enable my IDE to use 64 bit platform for building my DLL?
2. Where can I get a 64 bit compiler 64 bit windows 7 machine (Except visual studio compilers)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just switch over to MingW 64 bit.

[Get it here!](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I followed the link "Download MinGW-w64" which ends up taking me to the link "http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/". Here I see only tar.gz or tar.bz2 files. Which one should I pickup for my 64 bit windows 7 machine?

Comment: I believe WinRar will handl tar.gz files.  And that is one of the weaknesses (IMHO) of open source libraries.  Most are not professionally packaged so you get it, open it, then ask "what's next"?

Comment: I think if you do some googling, you may also find out how to install the Windows SDK and do command line compiles to 64-bit as well.